# Link to reputation leagues broken in private beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, private-beta

I decided to click the link to the reputation leagues at the bottom of the users page in the Programmers SE private beta. It brought me [to this page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/52/week/programmers), which is — not surprisingly — broken.

Could this link be hidden during the private beta? Or, alternatively, could we have the reputation leagues enabled for sites in this stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link no longer renders in the private beta case...since it would just lead you to a 404.

Comment: Woah, thanks for fixing and updating old bugs!